# Fancybox: Array variable not being passed

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Just can't seem to get this happening !

```
$(".fancy").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var pic = [];
  $('.room-thumbnail').each(function(index) {
      pic.push('\'' + 'http://localhost' + $(this).attr('href') + '\'' );
  });

  var pics = '['+ pic.join(', ')+']';

  console.log(pics);
  // => ['http://localhost/driver/images/produits/denim/sixthjune-7440/sixthjune-7440.jpg', 'http://localhost/driver/images/produits/denim/sixthjune-7440/sixthjune-7440-back.jpg', 'http://localhost/driver/images/produits/denim/sixthjune-7440/sixthjune-7440-closeup1.jpg', 'http://localhost/driver/images/produits/denim/sixthjune-7440/sixthjune-7440-closeup2.jpg']

  $.fancybox(pics, {
          'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
          'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
          'overlayColor'      : '#1D1D1D',
          'type'              : 'image',
          'cyclic': true
      });
});
```

If I enter the href urls ( pics ) manually it works.
But when I pass fancybox the variable ( pics ) i get the fancybox error :
- The requested content cannot be loaded. - Please try again later. -

Can someone tell me what I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$.fancybox(pics` I couldn't find a similar syntax in fancybox website. Where did you get that syntax?

Comment: There are two entirely different versions of fancyBox, each with their own website.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm usign Fancybox 1.3.4

Comment: @Vega - it's something I put togehter. But it should work...(???)

Comment: You have to create an array (containing objects or strings), but you have created a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but there is something that you are not considering:

Your declaration `var pics = '['+ pic.join(', ')+']';` is returning a *string* that fancybox cannot parse.

What you have to do is to convert such *string* into a javascript `object` so fancybox can parse it. There are different ways to do it. One is using the `eval()` function, but there can be security issues so this method is not recommended.

Since you are using jQuery, your safest way to do it is to use [jQuery.parseJSON( json )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

... so just right after the line where you set your variable `pics`

```
var pics = '['+ pic.join(', ')+']';
```

add this to convert it to a js object

```
pics = jQuery.parseJSON(pics);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Man you did it ! JFK, u da man !! The only thing also had to do to make it work from there was add double quotes to the array values: [code]pic.push('\"' + 'http://localhost' + $(this).attr('href') + '\"' ); and that did it. Thanks JFK.

Comment: 'pic.push('\"' + 'localhost'; + $(this).attr('href') + '\"' ); ' Ahh. I can't get the code to be highlighted properly. oh well.

Comment: use the key combination ALT + 096 (numeric pad) to get the "Grave accent" at the beginning and end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

1. create a container div with display property set to none **(display:none)**
2. inside of this container place de img tags
3. when you call the function trigger **click event** over the any image inside of div

example:

```
<div>
 <img ...></img ...></img ...>
</div>
```

on js code:
    $("#container img").fancybox();

```
function call_fancybox(){
$("#container img:first").trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work but I'm trying to get this to work. But if I can't I probably do it that way. Thanks anyways.