# fancybox manual call from array of image values

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a folder that contains images with a format like so,

> "_IMG(#).jpg"

where # represents the number of the given image in the gallery.

My idea is to use php to get the number of images in the gallery on the page load:

```
<?php
  $gallery_item = scandir("style/images/gallery");
  $ignore = Array(".", "..");
  foreach( $gallery_item as $img ){
    $i += in_array($img, $ignore) ? 0 : 1;
  }
?>
<script> var numImages = <?php echo $i; ?>;</script>
```

then, what I would like to do is preform some loop to create an array of image links based on the number of images in the gallery so I can call fancybox,

```
$.fancybox( imgArray, galleryOpts );
```

but I cannot figure out how to make this work with the jQuery syntax, because the format - as I understand it - must be like this:

```
$.fancybox([
    {'href' : 'some/path/to/image.jpg'}, 
    ...
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I don't have any of the images loaded on the page, hence the need for a manual call in such a way, and I'd like to be able to add more images to the directory and not have to do any more work.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9842741/1055987 or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10236934/1055987 to get an idea. You could pass `imgArray` as a variable with the required JSON format.

Comment: thanks, this helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] this is how I fixed this,

```
 for(i = 0;i <= numImages; i++ ) {
    galleryImg[i] = '{"href" : "style/images/gallery/_img ('+(i+1)+').jpg"}';
    galleryImg[i] = jQuery.parseJSON(galleryImg[i]);
  }
```