# fancybox 2 - supply image list at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Yeah, I'm a JS newb...I'll admit it.  I have a page with a list of addresses and various icons next to them.  One icon is supposed to bring up a fancybox 2 gallery of photos for that address.  The photos themselves are not initially displayed on the page, but loaded on demand.  I'm trying to pass the address ID and the number of photos to generate a list.  However, when I call it, it just brings up the fancybox with the string value of PhotoList instead of the photos.

```
function DisplayPhotos(ID, PhotoCount) {
    var PhotoList = '';
    for (k = 1; k <= PhotoCount; k++) {
        PhotoList += "{href: 'http://mydomain.com/images/image-" + MUID + "-" + k + ".jpg'},";
    }

    $.fancybox.open([PhotoList], {
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs: {
                width: 68,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

If I type them out into the function manually, it works.  Right now, I'm stuck...  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a type casting problem.  Fancybox was expecting an array, but receiving a string.  See updated code:

```
function DisplayPhotos(MUID, PhotoCount) {

    var PhotoList = '';

    for(k=1;k <= PhotoCount; k++){

        PhotoList += "http://mydomain.com/images/image-"+MUID+"-"+k+".jpg,";

    }

    PhotoList = PhotoList.substring(0, PhotoList.length - 1);
    var PhotoArray = PhotoList.split(',');


    $.fancybox.open(

        PhotoArray

    , {

        padding:0,
        helpers:{

            title:{
                type:'outside'
            },
            thumbs:{
                width:68,
                height:50
            }
        }

    });

    return false;

}
```

Comment: You could have parsed the string using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), check a similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10240551/1055987. Additionally, you may need to form a proper [JSON string format](http://json.org/) if you are using curly braces `{}` to set more than one name/value pairs (`href`, `title`, etc.)

Comment: And now you are creating a string value first, only to split it into an array afterwards … why don’t you create an array in the first place?